# Token Price from pancakeswap

Tags: tokens, txpool, bsc, pancakeswap

Actually i was wondering how to retrive the price of a low cap token from pancakeswap without having to use sites like poocoin/dextools directly.

I understood this,

1. U can use the pancakeswap api [here](https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-info-api/blob/develop/v2-documentation.md), but it doesn't work for every token
2. U can use directly the token pool  contract on bsc to retrive the price ( in this example assuming that the pool is BNB/Your token )

I'm going for the second way becouse it works for all the tokens, this is what I did:

- I red the main pancakeswap contract ( `0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E` ) and found this function used to calculate the price of tokens in output

```
function getAmountOut(uint amountIn, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) internal pure returns (uint amountOut) {
        require(amountIn > 0, 'PancakeLibrary: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT');
        require(reserveIn > 0 && reserveOut > 0, 'PancakeLibrary: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY');
        uint amountInWithFee = amountIn.mul(9975);
        uint numerator = amountInWithFee.mul(reserveOut);
        uint denominator = reserveIn.mul(10000).add(amountInWithFee);
        amountOut = numerator / denominator;
    }
```

- I converted the upper function in a javascript normal function to use it directly.

```js
function calcPriceInBnb( amountIn, reserveIn, reserveOut ){
    let amountInWithFee = amountIn *  9975 ;
    let numerator = amountInWithFee * reserveOut ;
    let denominator = ( reserveIn * 10000 ) + amountInWithFee ;
    console.log( numerator, denominator)
    amountOut = numerator / denominator;
    return amountOut;
}
console.log( calcPriceInBnb (
        1,
        parseFloat(reserves_._reserve1),
        toBaseUnit(reserves_._reserve0, 18, web3.utils.BN)
    ) ) // usage example
```

- now on the token pool (`0x1d42d057b765177298735c8d9f36b8208449dbb3`) I'm calling the function to retrive the pool reserves

```
function getReserves() external view returns (uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1, uint32 blockTimestampLast);
```

- Once that i have the reserves i call `calcPriceInBnb(1, reserve1, reserve0)` that returns the token price in BNB and from this i have only to convert the BNB value to USD.

There is only one problem that i'm finding, when i get the reseves from the pool i get a non floating number.

For example: I saw that `dextools.io` uses the same method to calculate the token's price, inspecting the requests on the website it uses json bojects with the following keys

```json
{
   "data":{
      "pair":{
         "token0":{
            "_id":"6096efc237e2488af0c1ea10",
            "id":"0x4a824ee819955a7d769e03fe36f9e0c3bd3aa60b",
            "name":"Kabosu",
            "symbol":"KABOSU",
            "decimals":9
         },
         "token1":{
            "_id":"6096efc237e2488af0c1ea11",
            "id":"0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c",
            "name":"Wrapped BNB",
            "symbol":"WBNB",
            "decimals":18
         },
         "info":{
            "address":"0x4a824ee819955a7d769e03fe36f9e0c3bd3aa60b",
            "holders":121190
         },
         "_id":"6096efc237e2488af0c1ea0f",
         "id":"0xa17d2c8b629095672633828d744a03608bbaae24",
         "createdAtTimestamp":1620504512,
         "exchange":"pancakev2",
         "type":"standard-pair",
         "tokenIndex":0,
         "__v":0,
         "initialReserve0":365615229923141.8,
         "initialReserve1":208.675,
         "creation":{
            "blockNumber":"7250792",
            "timeStamp":"1620504512",
            "hash":"0x4d1e5b7082d0a92885cad5a7047b2693c7e2790be0c591a622d602ef7318b3be",
            "nonce":"0",
            "blockHash":"0x7bdf8d219600934504103326070861fd3c99fefcbc9535592e042dd369686996",
            "transactionIndex":"213",
            "from":"0xb56fd23449d66a10251e7efa778c944c4ba96666",
            "to":"",
            "value":"0",
            "gas":"5956167",
            "gasPrice":"5000000000",
            "isError":"0",
            "txreceipt_status":"1",
            "input":"",
            "contractAddress":"0x4a824ee819955a7d769e03fe36f9e0c3bd3aa60b",
            "cumulativeGasUsed":"32279124",
            "gasUsed":"5956167",
            "confirmations":"235853"
         },
         "reserve0":165371362282732.84,
         "reserve1":7691.065744229067,
         "reserveUpdatedAt":1622012556573,
         "txCount":244654
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see at the end of the object there are two fields `reserve0=165371362282732.84` and `reserve1=7691.065744229067` that are floating numbers, if used in the `calcPriceInBnb` this numbers returns the correct price of the token.

Let's assume that i query the bsc pool contract in the same moment, instead of that values i would get `reserve0=16537136228273284`, `reserve1=7691065744229067` ( non float numbers ) and this bring me to wrong calc.

I thought that this had to do with the `decimals` of the tokens in the pool but didn't find correlations. Any idea?

### UPDATE

I made a gist on github about it https://gist.github.com/Linch1/ede03999f483f2b1d5fcac9e8b312f2c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to go through this hassle, you can use getAmount**s**Out on the PancakeSwap router contract to make this a lot simpler. You provide a path&amount of the first token in the path to use, and the function returns the token quantity you would receive at that moment. You can then use this data for price calculation.

Comment: Why do PooCoin is giving me a different value for the token price?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how you can get price for any token on Uniswap, Pancakeswap, SpookySwap, WannaSwap and so on... most of them were forked from original Uniswap contracts and share the same interface.

```js
import Web3 from "web3";
import { toWei, fromWei } from "web3-utils";

const abi = [
  {
    name: "getAmountsOut",
    type: "function",
    inputs: [
      {
        name: "amountIn",
        type: "uint256",
      },
      { name: "path", type: "address[]" },
    ],
    outputs: [{ name: "amounts", type: "uint256[]" }],
  },
];

const web3 = new Web3("<put_here_rpc_endpoint>");
const dexRouter = new web3.eth.Contract(
  abi,
  "<put_here_address_of_dex_router>"
);

const getTokenExchangeRate = async (tokenA, tokenB) => {
  return (
    await dexRouter.methods.getAmountsOut(toWei("1"), [tokenA, tokenB]).call()
  )[1];
};

// usage
const price = await getTokenExchangeRate(<addressForTokenA>, <addressForTokenB>)
```

Comment: I have only one token address thru which I'm going to find price, so will you please give me what is the value of `"addressForTokenB"`

Answer (score 0):

Token Price from pancakeswap, **solved on**

https://github.com/BrainSensorTechnology/BSC_Token_Price

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).